# Fetch bibtex citation with abstract included

Tags: bibtex, emacs

Hello to this great community,

I am trying to get a simple way to fetch bibtex citation with abstract. I know there is the option to use [Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) and convert the `nbib` file to `bib`, I am using  a [great](https://github.com/wash/pubmode) `Emacs` mode for doing this, but the downside is that I need to move all the time between `Emacs` and the browser. Is there the possibility to get the full citation using [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.it/) ?